# WPF setting the owner of a window to its parent window MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, window, parent

Hypothetically let's say I have an application where I have Users and Tasks, each User have different Tasks assigned to them. I have a MainWindow that lists the users, and when you click on a User a ManageTasksWindow is opened, showing the Tasks assigned to the User and on this ManageTasksWindow you can remove, update and assign Tasks to this User. If I want to add a new Task to the User an AddTaskToUserWindow will be opened on a button click. My problem is that the logic that handles the opening of this AddTaskToUserWindow is in a class called TaskLogic and I have no idea how to reference the currently opened SubWindow, so that I can set the AddTaskToUserWindow's Owner property to the SubWindow.

I have tried this:

```
AddTaskToUserWindow window = new AddTaskToUserWindow();
window.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ManageTasksWindow>().First();
window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
```

But I want a solution, where each AddTaskToUserWindow's Owner property can be set to the corresponding SubWindow.

Comment: If you were using mvvm. You'd have something like a userviewmodel which has an observablecollection of taskviewmodel. Add one of those taskviewmodels to a user's tasks and it wouod be turned into ui by a data template. No need to find a window, you manipulate data and ui is generated from that data. One of the many reasons mvvm is a de facto standard for commercial teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to ViewModel of the main window (say SelectedWindow or ActiveWindow) and set its value whenever you select a user. Then, listening to the NotifyPropertyChanged of the main window, your TaskLogic can find the ActiveWindow whenever it changes automatically.